# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS UI Scale settings - using cmdline

Tags: display, 20.04, gui, gsettings, scale-mode

I set up my Display Settings to scale for 200% like so:
[image: Display Settings]

When I run some apps (e.g. some games using Steam in Full Screen) it resets this setting after I exit the app.

I would like to create a shell shortcut to set this back.
Looking to know exactly what is being set by the "Screen Display" UI.

`gsettings list-recursively` gives out the same before and after the change... [See output](https://pastebin.com/LmSXaQ4W)

`xrandr` also... [See output](https://pastebin.com/DYpZgx7e)

So there must be some other setting that affects this and somehow gets changed with the UI.

Hope anyone knows what that is and how I can change that?

System Info:
[image: System Info]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing UI scaling from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087185/changing-ui-scaling-from-command-line)

Comment: @PRATAP Sorry but no. Saw this already. This does not do what the UI does. If changed so the UI will not reflect it.

Comment: I just tried it. after changing the scale via sed command gnome-shell refresh is required which is a minus if you dont wish to refresh.

Comment: @PRATAP I see. I didn't try that. Perhaps the UI does a refresh as well. Do you know how to do this refresh using a cmdline?

Comment: Yes.. First try Alt+F2 r Enter and see, If it works.. then lets go for another question how to refresh gnome-shell via command line..

Comment: Doesn't solve it. It does change the positions and sizes of some open windows. However the scale setting on the UI remains the same and not all components seem to respond the same as when the UI setting is changed. There must be something else being done by the UI....